# How to properly configure onedrive after having used "onedrive --monitor"?

Tags: 20.04

I have installed the linux onedrive client from abraunegg (https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive) on ubuntu 20 LTS from the ppa ([https://launchpad.net/~yann1ck/+archive/ubuntu/onedrive](https://launchpad.net/%7Eyann1ck/+archive/ubuntu/onedrive)).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yann1ck/onedrive
sudo apt update
sudo apt install onedrive
```

After one reboot I remarked that onedrive had synced all my folders at start-up. When changing things in the Onedrive folder, no sync was performed unless I did

```
onedrive --synchronize
```

When being confident enough about it's working, I tried to monitor with

```
onedrive --monitor
```

This successfully happened until I killed the process using ctr + C.

Next start-up I remarked that not only a sync was done at start-up, but also monitoring of updates were performed when powered on. **How do I explain this?** A process is visible (see more details at the bottom)

```
$ pidof onedrive
1602
```

and sending signals to it directly dis/enables the file syncing

```
kill -STOP 1602
kill -CONT 1602
```

However, no service has explicitly being started up. According to https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/USAGE.md, I should have done

```
systemctl --user enable onedrive
systemctl --user start onedrive
```

but I didn't (verified in the command history).

**Is the onedrive client properly configured? Or should I try to stop/kill the currently running process and perform the 2 preceding commands? And when I want to edit a configuration that requires**

```
onedrive --synchronize --resync
```

**what should I do then?**

Further details about the currently running process:

```
josja@sputter:~$ ps -Flww -p 1602
F S UID          PID    PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN    RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
0 S josja       1602    1590  0  80   0 - 246222 hrtime 26012  5 20:32 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/onedrive --monitor

josja@sputter:~$ systemctl status onedrive@josja.service
● onedrive@josja.service - OneDrive Free Client for josja
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/onedrive@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

josja@sputter:~$ systemctl status --user onedrive
● onedrive.service - OneDrive Free Client
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/onedrive.service; enabled; vendor pr>
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-01-04 20:32:49 CET; 2h 31min ago
       Docs: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive
   Main PID: 1602 (onedrive)
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/onedrive.service
             └─1602 /usr/bin/onedrive --monitor

jan 04 21:43:21 sputter onedrive[1602]: Sync with OneDrive is complete
jan 04 22:08:28 sputter onedrive[1602]: Starting a sync with OneDrive
jan 04 22:08:28 sputter onedrive[1602]: Syncing changes from OneDrive ...
jan 04 22:08:29 sputter onedrive[1602]: Sync with OneDrive is complete
jan 04 22:33:35 sputter onedrive[1602]: Starting a sync with OneDrive
jan 04 22:33:35 sputter onedrive[1602]: Syncing changes from OneDrive ...
jan 04 22:33:37 sputter onedrive[1602]: Sync with OneDrive is complete
jan 04 22:58:42 sputter onedrive[1602]: Starting a sync with OneDrive
jan 04 22:58:42 sputter onedrive[1602]: Syncing changes from OneDrive ...
jan 04 22:58:43 sputter onedrive[1602]: Sync with OneDrive is complete
systemctl list-unit-files
<...>
onedrive@.service                                                         disabled        enabled
<...>
```

**Update:**

From the answer and my experience it seems that the client has been started automatically by the ppa in a way that enables one to stop it and reconfigure it with

```
systemctl --user stop onedrive
onedrive --synchronize --resync
systemctl --user start onedrive
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclosure: I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

@Josja

This is a *bug* with the Ubuntu PPA Package.

To correctly install the client, you need to follow these instructions: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/ubuntu-package-install.md

Take note also of the *known issues* when using the Ubuntu Packages as per https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/ubuntu-package-install.md#known-issues-with-installing-from-the-above-packages

Comment: Does this mean that the ppa has done something that is equivalent to "systemctl --user enable onedrive; systemctl --user start onedrive" and that I should normally be able to "systemctl --user stop onedrive; onedrive --synchronize --resync; systemctl --user start onedrive"?

Comment: @Josja - I have no idea what the PPA package has done, what is configured and why it is doing this. It is best to probably file a bug against the PPA package, as the Debian package does not exhibit this behavior, thus, this is something very unique to the PPA package, thus, something that the PPA package developer has most likely implemented.